# Taylor series for the cosine function in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to build a Taylor series in lisp, as the following image.

```
1 + x^1/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3!.....etc
```

the power and factorial functions are already implemented in order to use them in taylor function.

currently i wrote the following initial code to solve the equation.

```
(defun taylor(x n)
(if (= n 0) 1
(+ (/ (power x n) (factorial n)) (taylor(x (- n 1))))))
```

using this code will cause the following error

> error: unbound function - X

---

im new in lisp, so any help will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis in front of `taylor`; i.e. you need to call it as `(taylor x n)` and not `(taylor (x n))`.

In general, errors like these are much easier to spot if you indent code appropriately, e.g. the following

```
(defun factorial (n)
    (if (= n 1)
        1
        (* n (factorial (1- n)))))

(defun power (x n)
    (if (= n 1)
        x
        (* x (power x (1- n)))))

(defun taylor (x n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (+ (/ (power x n)
              (factorial n))
           (taylor x (- n 1)))))
```